# Listview not showing in fragment but works perfectly in activity when fetching data from api.

Tags: android, json, api, listview

I have tried this code and it works perfectly in activity but I changed it to fragment and now the ListView is not showing up but I can see the data in logs but not in screen.

I have tried every solution given on this question already like return view at last etc still not working. Any help ? this is my Fragment code

```
public class BloodBankGovtFragment extends Fragment {
public static BloodBankGovtFragment newInstance() {

    return new BloodBankGovtFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bloodbank, container, false);

    final ListView listView1 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);



    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

   Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

    Call<Hospitals> call = api.getHospitals();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Hospitals>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Hospitals> call, Response<Hospitals> response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Hospitals hospitals = response.body();
            String[] hospitalsName = new String[hospitals.getRecords().size()];
            String[] ContactNumber = new String[hospitals.getRecords().size()];



            for(int i= 0;i<hospitals.getRecords().size();i++)
            {
                Log.i("hello", "onResponse: "+hospitals.getRecords().get(i).getBloodBankName());
                hospitalsName[i]= hospitals.getRecords().get(i).getBloodBankName();
                // ContactNumber[i] = hospitals.getRecords().get(i).getContactNo();

            }
            listView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, hospitalsName));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Hospitals> call, Throwable t) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "failed to fetch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

` 
and this is my fragment xml code.

`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/setting"
    android:background="#FFF"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_bloodbank_fragment" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: Are you sure the `ListView` is visible on-screen? What is the `layout_height` value on the root `View` in the `toolbar_bloodbank_fragment` layout?

Comment: Its height is match parent. below is the code.                           
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    >

</LinearLayout>

Comment: That's likely your problem. It's pushing the `ListView` out the bottom of the `LinearLayout`. Change it to `wrap_content`.